# Making and finding function $f(x)$ such that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Find(Make) a function like $f(x)$ that at $x=0$, $f(x)$ goes to $0$ ( not 0 ; $f(0)\neq 0$ , but $f(x)$ is going to $0$ as $x\to 0$)

Comment: Take any continuous function, such that it is $0$ at $0$, and add a discontinuity just at that point. For example $\delta(x)$

Comment: One example $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} -1\right)$?

Comment: The Dirac delta is not a function

Answer (score 3):

Define, $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, by,
\begin{align*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} -1, & \text{if $x\in (0,\infty)$ } \\
1, & \text{if $x=0$ }
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Also,.by using the fact of removable discontinuity, you can creat easily such functions,
As example,
\begin{align*}  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 &  x = 0 \\
x& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}